# How can I prevent a child component from unmounting so I can fetch data in it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm currently calling a child component in a very typical way, where I just have a list that I'm mapping out to return `Card`s.

```
const Header = () => {
    <View style={{ width: windowWidth - 40, backgroundColor: 'red' }} >
        {headerLayoutData && headerLayoutData.map((card, i) => {
          if (card && user){
            return <Card card={card} user={user} key={i} />
              }
          })
        }
    </View>
}
```

This is just called frmo another component, like this:

```
return (<View>
            <Header />
            ...
        </View>
)
```

I'm fetching data inside the `Card` components so if they mount and unmount, then mount/unmount, etc. it fetches data every single time and never stops.

Is there anything I can do to prevent `Header` from re-mounting `?

Comment: Might make more sense to move the fetching and storage out of the component so it can persist across remounts.

Comment: Is fetching never recommended to exist in a child component?

Comment: As a general rule I try to separate the data concerns from the rendering concerns, but it’s not necessarily absolute. Writing a hook that handles the fetching and caching is pretty straightforward for relatively simple cases.

Comment: Interesting. In what way would you use custom Hooks here? Would you call them from the parent or child component?

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll post an example of the type of thing I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment above, writing a hook to handle the data fetching and caching between remounts is relatively straightforward. This decouples the display concerns from the data fetching, which makes each piece generally easier to reason about, maintain, and reuse.

There's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-satoshi-23oze?file=/src/App.js) of what follows on codesandbox. This was thrown together quickly for demonstration purposes and I wouldn't necessarily ship it as-is. Having said that…

Consider a hook that provides data, loading status, error information, and a reload callback:

```js
const { data, loading, errors, reload } = useData();
```

This frees up the display component to focus on display concerns without worrying about where the data comes from:

```
function DataDisplay () {
  const { data, loading } = useData();

  return loading
    ? <div>Loading</div>
    : <div>(data display stuff)</div>
}
```

Nice.

Here's the hook. Detailed breakdown below.

```js
// a dumb "store" object that exists outside the hook scope
const store = {};

const useData = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: false,
    data: store.data
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      if (!state.data) {
        dispatch({ loading: true });
        fetchData().then((d) => {
          store.data = d;
          dispatch({
            loading: false,
            data: d
          });
        });
      }
    }

    load();
  }, [state.data]);

  const reload = useCallback(() => dispatch({ data: null }), [dispatch]);

  return { ...state, reload };
};
```

It works like this:

```js
const store = {};
```

It declares a "store" object outside the hook itself. `store` is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so every use of the hook refers to the same store variable, even if a component unmounts and remounts, or if multiple components need to display the same data in different places in the app.

```js
// just merges new properties with existing state.
const reducer = (state, action) => ({ ...state, ...action });

// internal hook state.
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
  loading: false,
  data: store.data
});
```

It uses [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to keep track of internal state (e.g. loading status and its own reference to the store's data)<sup>1</sup>. This state information will be returned by the hook for consumption by the component. It could be extended to keep track of errors and/or whatever else users of the hook might want to know about.

(The hook doesn't really need its own reference to `store.data` but clearing it from state provides a convenient way to trigger a reload, as explained below.)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      if (!state.data) {
        dispatch({ loading: true });
        fetchData().then((d) => {
          store.data = d;
          dispatch({
            loading: false,
            data: d
          });
        });
      }
    }

    load();
  }, [state.data]);
```

It invokes [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to load data. With `state.data` declared as a dependency this effect will run on initial component render and when `state.data` changes.

The effect declares and invokes a `load()` function.

If `state.data` isn't already present, it sets `loading` to true<sup>2</sup> and kicks off the asynchronous data request.

When the data request completes it updates `store.data` with the new information, resets `loading` to false, and updates the internal `state.data`. This triggers a component re-render.

```js
  const reload = useCallback(() => dispatch({ data: null }), [dispatch]);

  return { ...state, reload };
```

Finally, it returns the state data to the user of the hook, along with a `reload` callback that just clears the internal state.data, triggering the load effect to run again.

I hope this is helpful, and I apologize if it isn't clear. I'm tired and struggling to communicate clearly. There are implementation details that could be refined, but hopefully this provides some potential direction. Let me know if you have questions and I'll attempt to clarify.

---

<sup>1.  If you're not familiar with the useReducer hook you can think of it as an alternative to multiple useState calls here. You could accomplish the same thing using a separate useState for loading, data, etc..</sup>

<sup>2. Changing the `loading` state will trigger a re-render of the component, providing an opportunity to display a spinner or whatever.</sup>

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for doing this! Really helpful - I guess I'm still a little confused on why that hook would persist across being mounted/unmounted?

Comment: It persists because the hook puts the data into a `store` variable outside the hook's scope.